# Как применить фабричный метод в данном случае?

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

У меня есть два метода:

```
public interface IReader
{
    public Task<UserSettings> Read();
}

public interface IWriter
{
    public SettingState Write(ISetting setting, long id);
}

public class SettingWriter : IWriter
{
    public SettingState Write(ISetting setting, long id)
    {
       //do something
    }
}

public class SettingReader : IReader
{
    public  Task<UserSettings> Read()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Эти методы считываю настройки из `БД` или записывают. Я хочу их обьединить в фабрику методов.

```
public abstract class SettingFactory
{

    public abstract IWriter Write();
     

    public abstract IReader Read();

}
```

Так же у меня есть три наследника класса `ISetting`, который в зависимости от типа будут создать свой экземпляр методов `Reader` и `Writer`.

```
public class SettingNotebook: SettingFactory
{
    public override IWriter Write()
    {
        //do something
    }

    public override IReader Read()
    {
         //do something
    }
}
```

Но есть нюанс - `Writer` одинаковый функционал для всех, а `Reader` - нет. Как правильно это можно сделать, чтобы `Writer` не копировать в реализации фабрики каждый раз, а `Reader` переопределять?

Comment: В фабрике методы `Write()`, `Read()` надо бы переименовать в `CreateWriter()`, `CreateReader()`, не?

Comment: Если есть всего одна реализация `Writer`, то пусть фабрика `SettingFactory` имеет не абстрактный метод, а реализованный, который выдаёт нужный экземпляр. Соответственно, в наследниках его не нужно переопределять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можно реализовать метод `Write()` в родительский класс `SettingFactory`:

```
public abstract class SettingFactory
{
  public IWriter Write()
  {
    // do something
  }
  
  public abstract IReader Read();
}
```

А потом отдельно на каждый наследуемый класс указать `Read()`:

```
public class SettingNotebook: SettingFactory
{
  public override IReader Read()
  {
    //do something
  }
}

public class Setting2: SettingFactory
{
  public override IReader Read()
  {
    //do something
  }
}

public class Setting3: SettingFactory
{
  public override IReader Read()
  {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы создал базовый класс BaseSettingFactory:SettingFactory и в нем определил реализацию Writer.
Соответственно, все SettingNotebook и подобные наследовались бы от BaseSettingFactory.